# Android 2-Way TCP/IP ServerSocket/Socket Communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Using this [great tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) by the Java Code Geeks, I am easily able to create a client activity that sends data via TCP to a server's port 4000 using the following code:

```
public class Client extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Then using their other snippet for the server activity I can catch messages using TCP on that port:

```
public class Server extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

My question is how can I make it so these 2 can communicate back and forth?

```
Android -> Server(4000) -> Android(4001)?
```

In other words how can I make my app help the device act as both the client  (sending out data to another device on port 4000) and the server (listening for data on port 4001) at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need to? TCP sockets are bidirectional. The server can use the socket that is already open to send messages to the client.

Comment: Just setup an Input and Output stream on the socket for the server and have all communication happen on the server's port 4000?

Comment: Indeed! If you need a primer on sockets and bidirectional communication. There is a decent client/server tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: This not a 'great tutorial'. Some aspects of it are terrible. The `PrintWriter` should be created once, for the life of the socket, not once per message. Ditto the `BufferedReader`, which is all you need for communication in the other direction. As a matter of fact `PrintWriter` shouldn't be used over a network at all, as it swallows exceptions that you need to know about.

Comment: Thanks Dev, this was a trivial decision on ports made by a client (on sending to one port and receiving on another) and I have been racking my brain to figure out how to do so instead of using the default implementation like you are discussing. I think you've given me the support I needed though to push for the normal implementation. If you post an answer that outlines this superior option then I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

On the Server side change the port to 5000 (same as Client) instead of 6000:

And you need to update the following class because you don't want to create a new socket, you should use the one already created (in the Client part).
NB: the socket given as an argument to CommunicationThread is the socket that you supposedly already created (Client part).

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
            new Thread(commThread).start();

        }
    }
}
```